# Angular 2 how to render HTML in my header based on the current route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Basically, I have 3 routes and 3 different things I want to show based on which route I am currently on:

When route is `/`, I want to show in my header a link to FAQ.

When route is `/browse` I want to show in my header a Search input.

When route is `/photo:id` I want to show in my header a Add Favorite button.

So in my header code, which right now is just the below code, how can I handle those cases?

```
<div id="header">
  <!-- if route is / then just <a routerLink="/faq">FAQ</a> -->
  <!-- if route is /browse then just <input type="text"> -->
  <!-- if route is /photo:id then just <button>Add</button> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you have to go through the tutorial first https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: I did go through that, but in that case, they're adding an active class to make the text blue when they're on a particular route.  I want to render one set of HTML per route.  I could add a class hidden or something, but in react for example, I could render HTML based on the route, and my render function would just check my route and render the particular HTML.  How can I do that here?

Comment: so in react, I'd do checks like if (this.props.navigation.currentRoute="/") return (some html), else if (this.props.navigation.currentRoute="/faq) return (some html)

Comment: Have you tried using ng-if ?

Comment: with ng-if is there a route path match function or something?  i'm looking at the router documentation and I'm not able to find it :( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html